# Paypal: Enhanced checkout?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the paypal button to take donations, but I want the checkout screen to be the [Enhanced checkout.](http://www.snoep.at/labs/paypal/enhanced_checkout.png) as oppose to the [classic checkout](http://www.volksignia.co.uk/userimages/check-out-using-paypal.gif). Is there any way to make sure my donation button goes to enhanced?

Also, I'm willing to switch buttons to a buy now button if enhanced checkout is guaranteed. However, I don't know how I would allow the user to set his own price but I'll deal with that later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested simply having the button be buy now makes the checkout an enhanced checkout!